# Understanding the notation involved with differential of quaternion Exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, quaternions

I am reading [a paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwja-bHArbDjAhVItZ4KHcBODnoQFjABegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.47.201%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw0h2KYvoMqUaQ-LsIdBz84C) that describes the differential of a unit quaternion curve.

$dF_p$ denotes the differential of the following map at $p$
$$F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$$

Page 4 of the paper describes the Exponential map $exp : \mathbb{R}^3 \to S^3$ as follows

$$ exp(x,y,z)  = 
    \begin{cases}
      (cos||v||, \frac{sin||v||}{||v||}.(x,y,z)) & if ~~v=(x,y,z)\ne (0,0,0) \\
      (1,0,0,0)        &  if ~~v=(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)
    \end{cases} 
$$

Page 6 presents the following figure and an accompanying text explanation to help interpretation of $dF_p$
[image: exponential map illustration]

Explanation: 
[image]

In the above explanation what is $T_{log~q}\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

In the diagram, I can see $T_{1}S^3$ (tangent space to the standard quaternion (1,0,0,0)) and $T_{q}S^3$ (tangent space to a general quaternion $q$). But I do not know what is $T_{log~q}\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T_{\log q} \mathbb R^3$ is the local tangent space defined at $\log q$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$ defined by its tangent vectors $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$.

In the picture you see that $d \exp_{\log q}$ is sending the tangent vectors $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ attached at $\log q$ to a tangent space at $q \in S^3$ (depicted as a plane) defined by tangent vectors $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ passing through $q$ where $a_i = d \exp_{\log q}( e_i) \in T_q S^3$.

Comment: I have one doubt, the figure depicts d exp(log q) maps to TqS3. The map (derived in previous page as Jacobian) is a 4x3 operator and returns a 4x1 vector. Does that vector belong to TqS3?

Comment: Yes. While the tangent space at the identity quaternion, denoted as $T_1 S^3$, is isomorphic to $R^3$, the tangent space at an arbitrary quaternion, denoted by $T_q S^3$ is actually in a 4D linear space, which is why the standard exponential map and the principal logarithm are defined at the identity.